# Windows Mobile content encryption

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, cryptography, encryption

In my windows mobile application (v.6.x) I'm downloading media files onto the device. Is there a beaten path for encrypting this content? So that the media file can just be decrypted by the application, e.g. shuffle every 100th byte or something like that

Comment: Could you please add some tags, like "encryption", "decryption", "cryptography", etc.?

Comment: What's wrong with the suggestions so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might something like this work for you?

```
private Byte[] CryptoKey
{
    get { return new Byte[] { 0x0E, 0x41, 0x6A, 0x29, 0x94, 0x12, 0xEB, 0x63 }; }
}

public Byte[] Encrypt(Byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var crypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var key = CryptoKey;

        using (var encryptor = crypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key))
        {
            return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}

public Byte[] Decrypt(Byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var crypto = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var key = CryptoKey;

        using (var decryptor = crypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key))
        {
            return decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Found that in my notes from past C lectures. However I'll upvote for the use of "TransformFinalBlock"

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace in the Compact Framework which has several classes for encrypting and decrypting data, for example the [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) class which provides AES encryption.

In the example on the RijndaelManaged page on MSDN you can see an example on how to encrypt and decrypt the content of a file. You should be able to use the same technique for your media files.